# How to remove a button from an array of buttons

Tags: c#, arrays, button

I've created an array of buttons in my Windows Form.

```
Button[] buttons = {button1, button2, button3, button4, button5, button6, button7, button8, button9};
```

Once a button is clicked, I want to remove it from the array. I can't seem to do this in the event handler method?

```
void Button1Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e){
    buttonClicked(button1); //no effect on issue at hand

}
```

Comment: There isn't enough code here for us to see what you have tried. What happens when you try? Do you get an error? Does nothing happen?

Comment: Do you just want to remove the button from your list? Or do you want to remove the button from the Form?

Comment: I only want to remove it from the array

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Deleting from arrays is more complicated than e. g. from lists. If you store your `Button`s in a `List<Button>`, you could do something like:

```
void Button1Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    Button btn = sender as Button;
    buttonList.Remove(btn);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Something like this could work

```
void Button1Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e){
    buttonClicked(button1); //no effect on issue at hand
    buttons = buttons.Where(btn => btn != (Button)sender).ToArray();
}
```

Comment: It will work, however if the sender is not a button it wont. btn => btn != (Button)button1 than it will work if the sender can be different button.

Comment: @cerkiewny with `(Button)sender` you can have one event handler for all buttons, instead of having 9 handlers for button1, button2, ...

Comment: @Uriel_SVK yea, I know, but just marking the difference :)

Comment: @cerkiewny elaborate on the point u made about the event handler for all buttons, please? :)

Comment: @user3541263 If you want all the buttons to delete the button 1, change the lambda statement from btn => btn != (Button)sender to btn => btn != button1. Than assign the same event handler for all button, if you assign same event handler without change each button will delete itself from list after clicking.

Answer (score 1):

You can use IList instead of Buttons[] and use IList.Remove(itemForRemove) for delete item.